# Bash Sed Find & Replace With Special Characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to find `{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}` in the file `wp-config.php` and replace it with the contents of the bash variable `keysalts`.

```
keysalts=`curl -sS https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`
sed -i "s/{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}/$keysalts/g" wp-config.php
```

The following almost works, except that `keysalts` has a bunch of special characters such as $`;'" and sed is getting confused. Basically, how do I escape everything and just replace {AUTH-KEYS-SALTS} with $keysalts?

Thanks.

Comment: If using bash, there's no need to deal with sed for string replacement. Just use: `(contents="$(cat wp-config.php)"; result="${contents//'{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}'/"$keysalts"}"; echo "$result" >wp-config.php;)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way could be using `perl`:

```
perl -i -pe '
  BEGIN { 
    $keysalts = qx(curl -sS https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt) 
  } 
  s/{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}/$keysalts/g
' wp-config.php
```

Comment: The output of this was just outputted to standard out, how do I write the output of the perl to the file `wp-config.php`?

Comment: @Justin: With `-i` switch. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Birei How could this answer be modified to work with a standard `wp-config-sample.php` instead of just replacing {AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}. Some sort of foreach loop on each define?

Comment: @Brandon: I don't understand it. You should create a new question with your problem, that seems different of this one.

Comment: @Birei Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417651/perl-salt-generation-on-wp-config-sample-php

Answer (score 2):

You can escape `$keysalts` using sed itself:

```
sed -i "s/{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}/`echo $keysalts | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'`/g" wp-config.php
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern) for more information.

Comment: There are some characters that can still cause trouble in the `echo` command (`?`, `*`, multiple spaces, ...).  Use `echo "$keysalts"` or better yet `printf "%s" "$keysalts"` to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I like this [one better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution)

```
sed -i 's/{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}/'"$keysalts"'/g' wp-config.php
```

Personal choice.  :-)

Comment: Don't think this works, still `sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: Sorry, `'` not `"` to surround the expression.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you're asking the wrong question. I also asked the wrong question. The reason it's wrong is the beginning of the first sentence: "In my bash script...".

I had the same question & made the same mistake. If you're using bash, you don't need to use sed to do string replacements (and it's much cleaner to use the replace feature built into bash).

Instead of:

```
  keysalts=`curl -sS https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`
  sed -i "s/{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}/$keysalts/g" wp-config.php
```

you can use bash features exclusively, reading the file into a variable, replacing the text in the variable, and writing the replaced text back out to the file:

```
  INPUT=$(<wp-config.php)
  keysalts="$(curl -sS https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)"
  echo "${INPUT//'{AUTH-KEYS-SALTS}'/"$keysalts"}" >wp-config.php
```