# In bash how to replace string variable, and set it into sed command

Tags: bash, sed

in a bash script file, I have set one variable like this:

```
    current_path=`pwd`
    sed -i "1s/.*/working_path='$current_path';/" file1.sh
```

I want to run this script to replace the first line of `file1.sh` into `working_path='$current_path';`, but the `current_path` has the `/` and in the `sed` command, the `/` is predefined in `sed` replace pattern. 
And I have tried this:

```
    current_path1="${current_path/\//\\\/}"
```

the above line, I want to replace the `/` in variable `current_path` into `\/`, then input the `current_path1` into the `sed` command, but also has an error.

Could you give me some advice, please? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed scripting - environment variable substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution)

Comment: @tripleee, thank you. That post is very helpful. Maybe I couldn't find that post at that time I faced the question. Or I used different keywords so that the search engine didn't return the index of that post. Thus, I made a new post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
sed -i -e "1s@.*@working_path='$current_path';@" file1.sh
```

Use `@` instead of `/` in the substitute command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different delimiters for the `s///` command:

```
current_path=`pwd`
sed -i "1s|.*|working_path='$current_path';|" file1.sh
```

But you're not really searching and replacing here,, you want to insert the new line and delete the old line:

```
current_path=`pwd`
sed -i -e "1i\working_path='$current_path)';" -e 1d file1.sh
```

Are you really changing the first line of a `.sh` file? Are you deleting the she-bang line?

Comment: Yes, sir, when I run this `sed -i "1s/.*/working_path='\/home\/user\/Desktop';/" file1.sh` in terminal, it worked, but it will replace the `#/bin/bash` into `working_path='/home/user/Desktop;'`

Comment: My search and replace fails, any idea why?

`sed -i "s|\`"$foo"|\`"$bar"/g" "$file"`.

The error is: `command substitution: line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file;
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated \`s' command`

Comment: are those backticks supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

Please add a '/' to the beginning of pattern string. It replaces all matches of pattern with string.

```
 current_path1="${current_path//\//\\\/}"
```

Comment: Thanks, sir, Rafa's answer, the first answer, works.