# How to insert an arbitrary string after pattern with sed

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

It must be really easy, but somehow I don't get it… I want to process an HTML-file via a bash script and insert an HTML-String into a certain node:

org.html: `<div id="wrapper"></div>`

```
MYTEXT=$(phantomjs capture.js www.somesite.com)
# MYTEXT will look something like this:
# <div id="test" style="top: -1.9%;">Something</div>

sed -i "s/\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>/\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>$MYTEXT/" org.html
```

I always get this error: `bad flag in substitute command: 'd'` which is probably because `sed` interprets the content of `$MYTEXT` as a pattern as well – which is not what I want…

By the way: Duplicating `\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>` is probably also not necessary?

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/584894/951890

Comment: "`By the way: Duplicating \<div id=\"wrapper\"\> is probably also not necessary?`": Yes you can use backreferencing with `\1`; You need to enclose `\<div id=\"wrapper\"` in `()`. However, for static `search string`, that would be just a matter of convenience, not requirement.

Comment: Well, I did try this: `sed "s|(\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>)|\1$MYTEXT|" test.html` but I get this error in return: `\1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: Never mind – I am on a Mac which uses `BSD sed`. `\1` has to be replaced by `&`: `sed "s|(\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>)|&$MYTEXT|" test.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `/` in `$MYTEXT`'s `</div>` part is interpreted indeed as the final `/` in the `sed` command. You can choose another delimiter, which does not appear in `$MYTEXT`, for instance:

```
sed -i "s|\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>|\<div id=\"wrapper\"\>$MYTEXT|" org.html
```

Comment: This looks good! Which characters are allowed as delimiters? I need to choose a really rare one, because I don't know `$MYTEXT`s content. Using e.g. `†` leads to `error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Any character is permitted, even a control character such as Control-A or Control-G.

Comment: How would I insert Control-A which in my Terminal is the command to jump to the beginning of the line?

Comment: Hit Control-V before ; this will make the terminal not interpret the Control-A command

Comment: Or I can make use of [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and use something like `$'\001'` as a delimiter.