# Change variable value inside text file with Sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a text file containting this

```
Var1=ofzer
Var2=smelf
..
..
VarN=mskfm
```

I want to change the value of one of my variables using Sed. How is that possible?

Comment: Try searching on this site; you'll surely find examples.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1 - this is a simple example of substitution using sed.

Comment: You'll need to use a regular expression as an *address* to find the line to change. Then use the *"s" command* to change the value. Use the `-i` option to edit the file in-place. Here's the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed scripting - environment variable substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution)

Answer (score 20):

Say you wanted to change the value of Var2 from 'smelf' to 'smurf', you could use:

```
bash$ sed -i 's/Var2=.*/Var2=smurf/' file.txt
```

Comment: Suppose I want to set it to `${NEW_VALUE}`?  I can't use `${var}` inside of single quotes and, if I switch to double-quotes, the `.*` part doesn't work (does it?!)  So now what?

Comment: You can use double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want more complex substitution:

```
sed_param=s/Var1=.*/Var1=${NEW_VALUE}/  
sed -i "$sed_param" file.txt
```