# gedit plugin error - plugin loader 'python3' was not found

Tags: python, gedit, gedit-plugin

I tried to add some plugins in gedit 3.10.4 on ubuntu 14.04LTS and some errors occured when I try to activate those plugins in gedit:

> (gedit:20686): libpeas-WARNING **: Error initializing Python Plugin Loader: PyGObject initialization failed
>   ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError("No module named 'gi'",))
>
> (gedit:20686): libpeas-WARNING **: Please check the installation of all the Python related packages required by libpeas and try again
>
> (gedit:20686): libpeas-WARNING **: Loader 'python3' is not a valid PeasPluginLoader instance
>
> (gedit:20686): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python3' for plugin 'bracketcompletion'

And I see, on ged

> plugin loader 'python3' was not found

Does anyone have an idea from where the problem could come?

Answer (score 4):

I had this very same error with a different plugin ([reST](https://github.com/bittner/gedit-reST-plugin)). The problem the error was caused by was that I had run it from the command line **when a** [virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) **was active**. For this reason Python3 did not use (and find) the system libraries.

**Solution:** I ran gedit just normally from the GUI (or after deactivating the virtualenv in the Terminal), and the editor and the plugin just loaded fine. Double-check if you have a similar cause.

Otherwise you probably really have to check on what the error message says: Whether all "*related packages required by libpeas*" are installed. See details of package [libpeas-1.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpeas-1.0-0) for Trusty.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Railslide 's answer:

1. In your `/usr/lib/gedit/plugin` search for your plugin file (e.g. `bracketcompletion.plugin`) and change `Loader=python3` to `Loader=python`
2. If this still returns an error - likely because it doesn't match `python3` syntax: Use the command [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) as follows:

   ```
   cd python_directory/
   sudo 2to3 -f all -w *
   ```

e.g. for `gedit-latex-plugin`...

```
cd /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
sudo sed -i 's/python/python3/g' latex.plugin # only if you haven't already replaced python->python3
cd latex/
sudo 2to3 -f all -w *
```

Then this fixes the plug-in by replacing `python2.x` code with `python3` code

#### Related

- [Activating gedit-latex-plugin fails in Vivid](https://askubuntu.com/q/628925)
- [Gedit 3.8.3 only supports python3 plugins](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/121)

Comment: how to undo this command sudo 2to3 -f all -w *? because after this other applications such as anaconda are not working.

Comment: Could anyone help me with this please

Comment: I can only assume you didn't do it within the `latex/` directory and instead did it on maybe `lib/`. If you did do that, it is an exceptional blunder and you will need to reinstall all the broken libs or restore from a backup

Answer (score 0):

It's a gedit bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/859089

As a workaround, in your `/usr/lib/gedit/plugin` search for your plugin file (e.g. `bracketcompletion.plugin`) and change `Loader=python3` to `Loader=python`

Unfortunately, this workaround [doesn't work for all the plugins](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153#issuecomment-18626661).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not changing anything... Now the error is "pluging loader 'python' was not found"

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered essentially the same problem *today*, though with the code-comment plugin. In my case, the issue only showed up when gedit was executed from the command line, similarly to @Peterino (though no virtual environment had actually been explicitly set up). Everything was fine otherwise.

The reason why this happened seems to be linked to the fact that I have set up my `$PATH` in `.bashrc` in such a way that `python3` corresponds to a local **anaconda**/**miniconda** installation. An unwanted side effect is that, when launched from the terminal, `gedit` then actually picks the local miniconda install instead of `/usr/bin/python3.X`. (Checked by temporarily moving the miniconda folder elsewhere or login-in as another user).

#### Possible fixes

(Though I'm still not completely satisfied with either of them).

**Putting this in .bashrc works:**

```
export CONDAPATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin
export PATH="$CONDAPATH:$PATH"
# ^ put these two lines instead of the original miniconda export.

# __ : naming convention for private functions
__geditfix() {
    export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E "s|:$CONDAPATH\|$CONDAPATH:||g"); # remove conda from the PATH environment variable, using RegEx
    gedit "$@"; # call gedit, giving it all arguments
    export PATH="$CONDAPATH:$PATH"; # add conda to the PATH environment variable
} # Using a function rather than an alias, so that the filename is given to gedit, as it should and not to setconda().

alias gedit='__geditfix' # So that we can run our fix simply via: gedit <arguments>.
```

What this ^ does is to create an alias for gedit, using a function which actually

- 1) removes `~/miniconda3/bin` from `$PATH`,
- 2) runs gedit (`/usr/bin/gedit`), giving it all arguments,
- 3) puts back `~/miniconda3/bin` in our `$PATH`.

With these few lines in `.bashrc`, one can simply call `gedit <arguments>`

- the plugins work since gedit will pick `python` from `/usr/bin/`,
- `python`, `jupyter-notebook`, `conda`, and the like from miniconda can still be directly accessed without problem

btw, this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23134318/452522 (environment variables substitution in sed)

**Alternative solution:** install this v:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
```

As could be guessed from the terminal outputs it was missing when using the miniconda python3 install.

Comment: As of today, my favourite solution is to now instead use a virtual environment that I *only* activate when I explicitly want to work with python or jupyter in that specific terminal. I chose `venv`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

You can create a new environment (only needs to be done once) e.g. via: `python3 -m venv /yourpath/to/new/virtual/environment`

Then to activate it, simply do:
`source  /yourpath/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate`

And to deactivate it, simply type `deactivate`.