# 'python' plugin loader has not been enabled

Tags: python, gedit, ubuntu-17.10

I want to use plugin 'intelligent text completion' for gedit in Ubuntu 17.10 so I followed all the instructions [here](https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-intelligent-text-completion) but it was showing error like `plugin loader 'python3' was not found` and after searching this a lot on web I got this [question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964474/gedit-plugin-error-plugin-loader-python3-was-not-found/38235346) and again I changed python3 to python as mentioned and followed further steps in that but still it shows error like `libpeas-WARNING **: The 'python' plugin loader has not been enabled`
 Can anyone suggest something to clear this error I have been browsing on this for a long time.

Comment: If this problem only occurs when running gedit from the terminal and if a conda installation of Python was added to your PATH environment variable in .bashrc, then, hopefully what I found may also work for you. See that thread from 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53618945/452522.

Comment: If you try `python3 intelligent-text-completion.py` you should see the specific errors. Alot of them can be fixed using 2to3 but I ran into some more complicated ones like `ImportError: cannot import name Gedit` and the fix was to make a symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/girepository-1.0/Gedit-3.0.typelib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Gedit-3.0.typelib`. This isn't an answer because I got stuck on fixing an assertion error.