# use variables with special characters in sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I remove the last slash of my variable:

```
v="/my/path/"
echo $v | sed 's/\/$//' # echoes /my/path
```

Now I want to remove a pattern at the end of my variable. This pattern should be set in another variable:

```
pattern="/"
v="/my/path/"
echo $v | sed 's/"$pattern"$//'  # echoes /my/path/
```

It does not work. I tried escaping in case of special character such as "/" :

```
echo $v | sed 's/\"$pattern"$//'  # echoes /my/path/
```

None expected result either.

How should I proceed?

Comment: try `echo $v | sed "s/\\$pattern$//"`

Comment: Use different delimiters for sed like `s:::` instead of `s///` or just escape the `/` when you declare it. Also your gonna want your sed script in double quotes so that it expands the variable, but the `$` for the end of line in single quotes.

Comment: amdixon Double quoting the expression works. Why the double backslash?

Comment: so it doesnt interpret the dollar as the literal dollar character ( this would stop it expanding the pattern )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed scripting - environment variable substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *parameter expansion* inside single quotes, but inside double quotes.
Use

```
sed "s,$pattern\$,,"
```

However, to remove a pattern from the end of a variable, why not use the shell's mechanism? This avoids expensive forking and piping:

```
$ v="/my/path/"
$ echo ${v%/}
/my/path
```

Which also works with another variable holding the pattern:

```
$ pattern="/"
$ echo ${v%$pattern}
/my/path
```

Comment: Why escaping the `$`? It behaves the same without escaping it.

Comment: @kaligne To make it future proof: the shell implements a number of parameters with funny names, such as `$@`, `$_` and so on. If it ever implements `$,` you suddenly wonder why your script no longer works. Escaping it makes sure the `$` is always a plain dollar sign that anchors to the end-of-line.

Comment: @kaligne, I tend to be extra cautious with `$` sign, & try to keep only minimal required things outside single quotes. e.g. `sed 's,'"$pattern"'$,,'` It however appears dirty & less readable.