# sed command not working as expected

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Using sed command tried to match a value and then appending a value.
Comd is working fine without variable but not able to pass the variable as expected.

eg:-This comd is working fine

```
sed -i 's/\( *OOZIEUSERS1 *\)[^ ]*\(.*\)*$/\1, test1,\2/' sudo_file.txt
```

but when running tru varible its not working:-

```
#!/bin/bash -x
read -p "Enter the reference account name : " ACC
read -p "Enter the user name to be inserted into VISUDO : " UNAME
sed -i  's/\( *$ACC *\)[^ ]*\(.*\)*$/\1, $UNAME,\2/' sudo_file.txt
```

Comment: use double quotes to expand the variable

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes with sed. `sed -i  "s/\( *$ACC *\)[^ ]*\(.*\)*$/\1, $UNAME,\2/" sudo_file.txt`. Also see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/584894/1030675

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes `"` if you want bash to **expand** your variables:

```
sed -i  "s/\( *$ACC *\)[^ ]*\(.*\)*$/\1, $UNAME,\2/" sudo_file.txt
```

Comment: How do i change the command incase I want to make sure that UNAME gets added at the beginning of ACC instead of at the end.

Comment: that's another question... first search around on stackoverflow if any answer exists; if not add another question with some more information: what is the output you get; what would you want to get, wat have you tried,...