# Trying to figure out bash scripting with Sun Grid Engine

Tags: bash, sungridengine

I'm trying to use integer variables within a bash script for submitting to Sun Grid Engine (using qsub).
Can someone clarify why this does not work?

`NUMCORES=32`

`#$ -pe mpi $NUMCORES`

(gives the error "Unable to read script file because of error: Numerical value invalid!
The initial portion of string "$NUMCORES" contains no decimal number)

But this does:

```
#$ -pe mpi 32
```

I've looked at some solutions which involve awk or bc but can't seem to make them work.  Obviously I am new to bash scripting - thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it really a bash script? What is the first line? What do you mean by *"the initial portion of $NUMCORES contains no decimal number"*? Does the subsequent portion contain decimals? You show it as containing precisely `32` or are you not being wholly truthful?

Comment: Same script, or are you missing a `export NUMCORES=32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `#` in a bash script signals comments. Hence, in the line `#$ -pe mpi $NUMCORES`, the value of the environement variable `NUMCORES` will not be used, since it is a comment.

Yet, these comments are useful to pass parameters to the `qsub` command. See [the man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/manuals.html) and [these examples](http://bioinformatics.mdc-berlin.de/intro2UnixandSGE/sun_grid_engine_for_beginners/how_to_submit_a_job_using_qsub.html) for instance. Notice that these parameters can be passed on the command line:

```sh
qsub -pe mpi 32 myjob.sh
```

The alternative is to use a command before qsub to generate the job. Let's imagine that the job script `jobgeneric.sh` is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N useless
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi $NUMCORES
#$ -l h_vmem=6G

echo 42
```

Let's use the [`sed` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands) to substitute the environment variable and create a new file `job.sh`:

```sh
export NUMCORES=32
sed 's/$NUMCORES/'$NUMCORES'/g' jobgeneric.sh > job.sh
cat job.sh
```

See also [Environment variable substitution in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution) . The result is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N useless
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 32
#$ -l h_vmem=6G

echo 42
```

Now the job can be submitted by using `qsub job.sh`!

Comment: Thanks francis.  I ended up taking a similar approach using python to handle specifying cores and other parameters prior to generating the script.  Then the script gets automatically submitted to the queue.