# Using tr or sed to prepare string for MySQL input

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, tr

I've been searching around for a solution to my problem, being that I have a bash script recursively inputting data into a MySQL database.

Sometimes, the string I want to input contains single quote marks, and this is where my coding becomes stuck.

I want to run a sed or a tr filter over the string before I send it to my SQL processing, and use it to change single quotes to an escape character followed by the same quote, e.g. from `'` to `\'`.

I have tried the following off other suggestions but the output remains unaltered:

```
string="Karl's Oil Lamp"
find="'"
replace="\\\'"
echo $string | sed -r 's/$find/$replace/g'
```

I can see that my string remains unchanged with the output being `Karl's Oil Lamp`.  I have similar luck when using tr though that may not be the solution I need anyway.

Any kind suggestions?  Running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following ***sed*** expression:

```
sed "s/'/\\\'/" <<< $string
```

The output:

```
Karl\'s Oil Lamp
```

Answer (score 0):

With parameter expansion, no external tools:

```
$ string="Karl's Oil Lamp"
$ echo "${string//\'/\\\'}"
Karl\'s Oil Lamp
```

This is an expansion of the form `"${parameter//pattern/string}"`, replacing all occurrences of *`pattern`* with *`string`*. *`pattern`* is a single quote, which we have to escape `\'`, and *`string`*  is a backslash and a quote, both of which we have to escape `\\\'`.

---

The reason your try fails is that single quotes prevent parameter expansion, see [Environment variable substitution in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution).