# Trouble using sed to replace contents of .coveralls.yml configuration in Travis-CI

Tags: sed, travis-ci

I'm trying to take an environment variable in travis-ci and replace the contents of a file at runtime using `sed`.

The file in question contains:

```
service_name: travis-ci
repo_token: COVERALLS_TOKEN
```

On an ubuntu system, using `sed -i 's/COVERALLS_TOKEN/ASDF/g' .coveralls.yml` in the command line works, but carrying that over to the travis-ci configuration something like `sed -i 's/COVERALLS_TOKEN/$COVERALLS_TOKEN/g' .coveralls.yml` doesn't pull the environment variable.

What really throws me off is that I have a project today where the below `.travis.yml` entry works, but adapting it to this circumstances it doesn't.

**Original implementation, still works today**

```
sed -ri 's/^MY_ENV_VAR=/MY_ENV_VAR='$MY_ENV_VAR'/' .env
```

**Adaptation (doesn't work)**

```
sed -ri 's/^COVERALLS_TOKEN/$COVERALLS_TOKEN/' .coveralls.yml
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variable substitution in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/environment-variable-substitution-in-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with your command.  First, the `^` means it will only match `COVERALLS_TOKEN` where it occurs at the very beginning of a line. Since it's not at the beginning of a line in your YAML file, there is no match and the `sed` command does nothing.

Second, there is no variable substitution inside single quotation marks.

So remove the `^`and use double quotes instead of single ones:

```
sed -ri "s/COVERALLS_TOKEN/$COVERALLS_TOKEN/" .coveralls.yml
```

Some notes:

1. The variable `$COVERALLS_TOKEN` must be set in the shell at the time that you run the `sed` command.
2. The substitution will fail with a syntax error if the value of `$COVERALLS_TOKEN` contains the delimiter you use on the substitution command. The command above uses `/`, but you can change that if needed - just pick something that doesn't occur in the token string.
3. The token value will not be quoted in any way in the YAML file. Normally that's ok, but if there are any weird characters in the value, you will need to put quotes around it in the YAML by adding them to the replacement side of the substitution command as well:

   ```
   sed -ri "s/COVERALLS_TOKEN/'$COVERALLS_TOKEN'/" .coveralls.yml
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this was the detail I needed.  It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes suppress variable expansion.

Comment: Are you suggesting it should be `sed -ri 's/^COVERALLS_TOKEN/"$COVERALLS_TOKEN"/' .coveralls.yml`?  Unfortunately that's not working.  I also tried `sed -ri 's/^COVERALLS_TOKEN/'"$COVERALLS_TOKEN"'/' .coveralls.yml` given the "possible duplicate" flag on this.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting `'s/^COVERALLS_TOKEN/'"$COVERALLS_TOKEN"'/'`. What is your problem with that command?

Comment: @Webnet Well, it works for me. Are you using `sed` in the usual fashion (shell), or in some bizarre environment in which your variable is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me.

```
sed -ri 's,IMAGE_REPOSITORY,'"$IMAGE_REPO"',g' chart/values.yaml
```