# Need help in sed command to add variable in a text file after reading from a grep command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am working on a script to read variables from different log files using a `grep` command and after reading the result, I want to add that variable into a txt file in front a predefixed text.

This is what i am doing

```
echo "whats your environmentprefix"
```

based on userinput, i am doing this

```
read $environmentprefix
```

Now this  `$environmentprefix` value needs to be replaced in a `config.txt` file

where text is present as `input.queue=_mq.test`

I want to add this variable in front of this , so that it looks like

```
input.queue=$environmentprefix_mq.test
```

I have tried all sed commands but unable to get the desired output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variable in sed command in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691071/how-to-use-variable-in-sed-command-in-shell)

Comment: `sed -i "s/input.queue=_mq.test/input.queue=${environmentprefix}_mq.test/" filename`?

Comment: Thanks , but that didnt woked, the result is coming as           input.queue=_mq.test only the variable is not getting appended. Am i doing correct, that i am asking for a user input and then doing read $environmentprefix and using that $environmentprefix into the above sed command

Comment: sample code posted should work. Be sure you copy/paste the variable name from your declaration, ie. `var=something; sed -i "s/input=xxx/input=${var}_mq.test/" file` And you seem to understand the difference between a single-quoted `sed` script versus a dbl-quoted version. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It should work :

```
read -i "Whats your environment prefix : " environmentprefix
sed -i "s/input.queue *= *.*/input.queue=${environmentprefix}_mq.test/g" file
```

Regards!

Comment: This solved the issue and is working as expected, thanks for the help, really appreciated