# Parameterize running docker image in service fabric

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric

I have a docker image that I want to run in service fabric with parameters (such as running command 'docker run  -ParameterName parameterValue').

I can pass parameters to docker run in Commands section of ServiceManifest.xml:

```
<ContainerHost>
    <ImageName>...</ImageName>
    <Commands>-ParameterName parameterValue</Commands>
</ContainerHost>
```

Is there a way to fill Commands section of ServiceManifest in ApplicationManifest.xml file?
I know that there is an ImageOverrides section in ApplicationManifest to override the ImageName of ServiceManifest, is there a similiar section to override the Commands section? I want to be able to specify the parameterValue in ApplicationParameters file.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is linux based. you can change the file by using 'sed' command

You can create a shell script file and put it in the docker run command.

[Environment variable substitution in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/environment-variable-substitution-in-sed)