# Using sed to replace to a var with special characters

Tags: sed

I want to replace a placeholder on a file `<<string>>` in the example to the contents of a var that has several special characters.

file.txt

```
My string: <<string>>
```

script.sh

```
STRING="something-else;device=name.of.device;key=abcd1234/wtp="
sed -i "s/<<string>>/${STRING}/g" file.txt
```

I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 165: unknown option to `s'
```

I already use this `sed` command for other vars that do not have special characters. Any way to escape the var ${STRING} entirely?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `STRING` contains a `/`, you should use a other delimiter, for example, you can use `^` like so:

```sh
sed  's^<<string>>^'"$STRING"'^g' file.txt
```

The quoting logic (`''""''`) is explained nicely [on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584926/5625547).

---

Example on my locale machine:

```
$
$ cat file.txt
My string: <<string>>
$
$
$ STRING="something-else;device=name.of.device;key=abcd1234/wtp="
$
$
$ sed -i 's^<<string>>^'"$STRING"'^g' file.txt
$
$ cat file.txt
My string: something-else;device=name.of.device;key=abcd1234/wtp=
$
$
```

Comment: or skip the `''""''` and  use double quote for the entire script: `sed "s^<<string>>^$STRING^g" file.txt`

Comment: The script in the answer would fail if `STRING` contained `^`, or `&`, or `\1` (and some less likely others such as a newline).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this job easily and robustly with sed, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed). Instead just use a tool like awk that understands literal strings:

```
$ string='~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={[}]|\:;"'\''<,>.?/\1'

$ echo "$string"
~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/\1

$ string="$string" awk -i inplace 'match($0,/(.*)(<<string>>)(.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] ENVIRON["string"] a[3] } 1' file.txt

$ cat file.txt
My string: ~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/\1
```

That above will work for any characters (or backreference substrings like `\1`) that `string` might contain because it's simply using a literal string operation (concatenation) for the replacement.

It's using GNU awk for `-i inplace` just the same as your original script used GNU sed for `-i`.

Don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names by the way to avoid clashes with exported and built-in variables and not obfuscate your code by making it look like you're using exported variables, see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Note that if you have multiple `<<whatever>>` placeholders you can easily parameterize the above, e.g.:

```
$ foo='Now is the Winter'
$ bar='Of our discontent'

$ cat file.txt
My foo string: <<foo>>
My bar string: <<bar>>

$ foo="$foo" bar="$bar" awk -i inplace 'match($0,/(.*)<<(\w+)>>(.*)/,a) && (a[2] in ENVIRON){ $0=a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3] } 1' file.txt

$ cat file.txt
My foo string: Now is the Winter
My bar string: Of our discontent
```

If you don't want to set `foo` and `bar` on the awk command line you can export them before it, or read them from a config file or a here-doc or ... - lots of options.